# How can I prove the metrics will hold, given a matrix from a given space?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, metric-spaces, physics, mathematical-physics

The Minkowski distance is defined as: $$\sum_{i=1}^n (|x_i-y_i|^p)^\frac{1}{p} $$

Also, the norm of a vector can be defined as the $ ||x|| = \sqrt{x^T\bullet g\bullet x} \text{, g is the metric matrix}$ . If $ p = 2 $, this means it is the euclidean space and for that reason the $ g_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{pmatrix}$.

In physics, when you are dealing with the Minkowski space the metric matrix could be defined as $$ g_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\
    \end{pmatrix}. $$

For the Euclidean space, I know that it holds the properties of *Positivity*, *Symmetry* and *Triangle* *Inequality*.

For that reason, I'm wondering, if there is a way, knowing which matrix is the matrix metric, if it is possible to prove the properties that will be valid.

I might said that the prof of the *Symmetry* could be made by showing that $g^T = g^{-1}$, which is the case for $g_1$ and $g_2$. In the case of *Positivity*, I could prove showing that $det(g) = 1$, which is not the case for $g_2$. Could you tell me if this is the correct approach? Also, about the *Triangle Inequality*. How can I prove, knowing the matrix, if the property will be valid for the given space?

---

Note: I have no formal background in mathematics, as I'm a student in the third period of engineering. So, please don't judge too hard my prof approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is correct that symmetry is equivalent to the matrix $g$ being symmetric.

Positivity is equivalent to $g$ being positive definite, which is equivalent to $g$'s eigenvalues being all positive.
Notice that if $g$ is symmetric, the Spectral Theorem guarantees that $g$'s eigenvalues are real.
Clearly, your $g_2$ above fails positivity, since it has an eigenvalue $-1$ $($with multiplicity $3)$.

Moreover, observe that this does *not* have much to do with the $\det(g)$.
Since the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues, the most we can say is that if $\det(g)\leq0$ then positivity fails.
In particular, we may have $\det(g)>0$ without $g$ being positive definite $($such as when $g=-I$ on a space of even dimension$)$, and $g$ may be positive definite with $\det(g)\neq 1$ $($such as when $g=\lambda I$ for some positive $\lambda \neq 1)$.

Finally, if $g$ is symmetric and positive definite, then the bilinear form $x^Tgx$ defines an inner product, and hence $\lVert x \rVert = \sqrt{x^Tgx}$ **is** indeed a norm.
In other words, we get the triangle inequality automatically from symmetry and positive-definiteness.

Comment: That is right what I needed. I'm impressed, even though I have read all the linear algebra book, this simple definition of norm is not covered. Obrigado

Comment: De nada. :) Every inner product $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ induces a norm via $\lVert x \rVert = \sqrt{\langle x,x \rangle}$, but the converse is not true. Indeed, the converse is true if and only if the norm satisfies the [parallelogram law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law); in this case, we may recover the inner product using the [polarization identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity). A simple example of norm for which the parallelogram law does not hold is the [taxicab (or Manhattan) distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry).